# Bijection between the coset of the Young-subgroup and (p,q)-shuffles

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n=p+q$ and $I$ be a subset of the natural numbers up to $n$ with $p$
elements. I have to show, that there is a bijection between
$S_n / Y_I$ where $Y_I$ is the Young-subgroup and all $(p,q)$-shuffles.

Could someone please help me or give me a hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Coxeter presentation of $$S_n=\langle s_1,\ldots,s_{n-1}\mid s_i^2=1, \;s_is_j=s_js_i\mbox{ if }|i-j|>1,\;s_is_{i+1}s_i=s_{i+1}s_is_{i+1}\rangle$$
Show that a minimal length coset representative in $S_n/S_p\times S_q$ is a shuffle of the sets $\{1,\ldots,p\}$ and $\{p+1,\ldots,n\}$. (This is probably easiest to see if you know how to represent $S_n/S_p\times S_q$ diagramatically.)

I guess you could also just show that the number of $(p,q)$-shuffles is $\displaystyle \frac{n!}{p!q!}$, but this misses the deeper connection.